# KDiff3 (on Windows): ignore Line end style

Tags: windows, kdiff3

I´m comparing two versions of a C code, and some files differ only for the Line end style (Unix or DOS).

How can I tell KDiff3 to ignore such difference?

Note:

- I cannot pre-process the code with dos2unix on one of the two
  versions
- I´m using Windows

Thanks!

EDIT:

this seems to do part of the trick (all files are then shown as DOS style):

```
Settings>Configure KDiff3..>Diff>Preprocessor command: sed "s/+/ /g"
```

Comment: Your edit should be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

For directories :

- Settings>Configure KDiff3..>Directory>

  - File Comparison Mode -> Full analysis
  - Whitespace differences considired equal -> check

Comment: The comparison is much slower BUT this did the trick! Now all files that suffer from Windows/Unix line ending has green status (except those with real text difference).